# Drawing a set of VBOs with one draw command in OpenGL. Is there a glMultiDrawElements for VBOs?

Tags: opengl

I have a few hundred VBOs, and I want to only draw a subset of the VBOs each frame.

Is there anything faster than binding and drawing each VBO? Is there a batched draw command for multiple VBOs?

1. How do I bind multiple VBOs?
2. Is there a version of glMultiDrawElements for sets of VBOs?

Comment: Which GL version?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is solved by trying to stuff as much as possible into a single VBO. You can store multiple, unrelated primitives/meshes in a single VBO and then separate them with array indices/ranges.

Binding multiple VBOs or drawing from a set of VBOs is not possible, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

There is extension called primitive restart, which can maybe help you, but you will have to have only one big VBO.

Also - if you want to use multiple VBOs, you can try extension unified buffer memory, which is faster then binding.

But what I know, there is no way to draw multiple VBOs (you can have bound only one VBO at a time).